# Beaker Notebook start Anaconda Python on Windows

Tags: ipython, anaconda, beaker-notebook

How should I configure Beaker to use my pre-installed Anaconda Python3? I followed the instructions [here](http://beakernotebook.com/getting-started?windows&scroll), and then [here](https://github.com/twosigma/beaker-notebook/wiki/Language-Preferences), but with no success. My `beaker.pref.json` file looks like:

```
{
  "autocomplete-parameters" : "true",
  "pref-format" : "1",
  "allow-anonymous-usage-tracking" : true,
  "languages" : {
    "IPython" : {
      "path" : "c:\\Python\\Anaconda"
    },
    "Python2" : {
      "path" : "c:\\Python\\Anaconda\\envs\\py27"
    },
    "Python3" : {
      "path" : "c:\\Python\\Anaconda"
    }
  },
  "advanced-mode" : false,
  "edit-mode" : "default"
}
```

I tried it without `Python2`, but still not work. My browser always open, but it's unable to connect to the server.

The output of `beaker.pref.json` run is:

```
...
c:\Beaker>REM limitations under the License.
starting nginx instance (c:\Beaker/nginx)
nginx-stderr>nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: CreateFile() "C:\Users\itsme\.beaker\v1\nginx8685613245756631317/logs/error.log" failed (1113: Form
atMessage() error:(15100))
nginx-stderr>2016/04/29 16:03:50 [emerg] 3548#14984: CreateFile() "C:\Users\itsme\.beaker\v1\nginx8685613245756631317/conf/nginx.conf" failed (1113: FormatMes
sage() error:(15105))
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-8.1.13.v20130916
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector - Started SelectChannelConnector@127.0.0.1:8802

Connecting to http://127.0.0.1:8801/
```

Of course, `Jupyter` works perfectly.
Thank you for any help!!

Answer (score -1):

It looks like BeakerX is the successor of Beaker! Check [BeakerX](https://github.com/twosigma/beakerx) over the Internet.

**To install it, just do: conda install -c beakerx beakerx**

Don't use Beaker anymore, otherwise, you may lose much time trying to solve it.